# Firebase Dynamic Link, how to direct users to app if app is installed

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

The debug mode shows two tests I don't quite understand

> App Installed? Use Custom Scheme YES or NO

How do I make the answer YES for `Use Custom Scheme` ?

> App Installed? Use Universal Links : YES or No

Again, How do I make sure I'm using Universal Links so the answer to the question is `YES`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To support Firebase Dynamic Links for all versions of iOS you need to implement both Universal Links and custom schema. FDL just decides for you that on older iOS versions it should use custom schema, because Universal Links are not supported (it appeared only in iOS 9).

So the answer is actually quite simple: **you can't choose**. Debug mode doesn't only show you what you can change, in this case it **just shows you what is the actual flow in case app is installed or not**. Here it just serves as explanation for you of how it works.

So if app is installed and iOS is lower than 9, it will always use custom schema. If the app is not installed, it will always ask user to install the app. There is nothing to change here, because this makes sense.

And if you are asking if you can do something else (apart from redirecting to AppStore) if app is not installed, you can also redirect user to custom URL:

[image]